# updating mongoose json object doesn't seem to work

Tags: json, mongoose, nested

I am not getting any errors or faults, but with the schema below I can't seem to update the fact1.nested1.

If not using a nested Json it works, so I manage to update nested1 by using

```
$set: {'nested1': req.body.newNested1}
```

But whatever I try updating it as per below doesn't change anything. I did some research and I tried most solutions, has anything changed in mongoose?
Are there other ways to update nested Jsons without changing all other data in the Json.

```
var mongooseSchema  = new Schema ({
fact1: {
    type: JSON,
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 300,
    required: true,
    default: "emptyType"
}})

    var setObj = {
    $set: {'fact1.nested1' : req.body.newNested1}
  }
    User.FactCheck.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{ 
             setObj}
            , {
                upsert: true,
                'new': true
            }).exec(function(err, doc) {


                if (err) return res.send(500, {
                    error: err
                });

                console.log (doc)
                return res.send(doc);
            });
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think `type: JSON` is valid. Is `fact1` a JSON-formatted string or an object?

Comment: Hi in my schema it is called type: JSON I thought it is a valid type, I did realise now that as per the added attachment it mentions object. So coinFactTransparent is fact1 and coinbooltransparent is nested1.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me I also adapted the schema as per below. Also I believe adding more parameters than just setObj (for instance   (id,setObj, anotherParam) may have been the reason why it wasn't working as this was the last thing I changed.
Nothing else worked for me even though no errors.

```
     var mongooseSchema  = new Schema ({
     fact1: {
        nested1: Boolean,
        nested2: String     
     }})


    objForUpdate.fact1 = {}
    objForUpdate.fact1 = {  'nested1' : req.body.newnested1,
      'nested2' : req.body.newnested2}

    User.SCHEMAPLAYER.findByIdAndUpdate(id,setObj
            , {
                upsert: true,
                'new': true
            }).exec(function(err, doc) {


                if (err) return res.send(500, {
                    error: err
                });

                console.log (doc)
                return res.send(doc);
            });
```